# Javascript for...in loop using empty object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have inherited a code base that contains the following:

**Javascript / JQuery**

```
('.text_transition').on('change', function()
{
    var keycode = $(this).val();
    var $el = $(this).closest('.js-builder').find('.js-preview');
    var $new_p;
    var $parent = {};
    var attributes = [ 'font-family', 'font-size', 'top', 'position', 'left', 'width', 'height', 'text-align', 'color' ];
    var attr_object = {};

    for ( var prop in attr_object )
    {
        if ( attr_object.hasOwnProperty( prop ) )
        {
            // ....Do something
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="inputContainer">
    <select name="page_1_text_transition" class="text_transition">
        <option value="swing_sync" data-json="{&quot;id&quot;:6,&quot;unique&quot;:&quot;swing_sync&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Swing + Sync&quot;,&quot;order&quot;:0}">Swing + Sync</option>

        <!-- etc.... -->
    </select>
</div>
```

Very basic... on change, do something.

I can't figure out how it's working with the object `attr_object` being empty?

Comment: That doesn't look right. Can you create a sample fiddle?

Comment: I do not see that working...

Comment: Exactly, this is my frustration :) It appears to be working on the live site. http://www.ecardshack.com/ if you build an eCard, it relates to the first text animation selector

Comment: @SamHolguin Can you create a sample fiddle? Sharing a website's like will not help us, since it will have tons of other code and we will have to search specific code to debug. Can you share a *minimal working example*

Comment: On with it now, cheers